# LaunchImage in Images.xcassets with Launchscreen.xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, launchimage, launch-screen

I'm using Xcode 6 with iOS 8 and 7, I have a `Launchscreen.xib`, and in `General Target` I've well configured my project :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByJ6G.png

But I think `Launchscreen.xib` doesn't work on iOS 7.1.

So I've made `LaunchImage` in `Images.xcassets` for other iOS which doesn't support `Launchscreen`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFbgD.png

I don't know why, that makes me 2 warnings :

```
/Users/../Desktop/ProjectName/ProjectFolder/Images.xcassets: The launch image set "LaunchImage" has 2 unassigned images.
```

How to fix it and use only `Launchscreen.xib` (if that works for every iPhone/iPad, or use my two images in `LaunchImage` (`Images.xcassets`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to fix it and use only Launchscreen.xib (if that works for every
>   iPhone/iPad, or use my two images in LaunchImage (Images.xcassets)

Launchscreen.xib is a feature of iOS 8, so if you are targeting iOS 7 You should add launch images.

What worked for me is to leave Launch Screen File field empty and to use assets catalog with launch images. I tried to use both together but I couldn't make good results...

[image]

Comment: Ok ! So I'll leave Launchscreen.xib too ! How do you have all this settings in images.xcassets ? look my comments below please, and tell me how can I have all settings like on your screenshot ?

Comment: It's ok, I've found ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using LaunchScreen.xib

If you want to use LaunchScreen in Images.xcassets, you need to do following

1. Launch Screen File is empty

   [image]
2. Also you can set the icons for different devices and other options from here

   [image]

Comment: Yeah It's what I I've done... no ?
But why my Images.xcassets is like that : http://i.imgur.com/93Akwbq.png

I don't have the same options like you...

Comment: You need to click "Show the Attribute Inspector", more over in your http://i.imgur.com/cKLcBzS.png, the Launch Screen file is not empty. It is set to LauchScreen.xib, it should be empty

Comment: "Show the Attribute Inspector" is on top right , next to question mark in circle

Comment: Please have a look, I've modified like you said : http://i.imgur.com/XKyLPb4.png my general project settings. So now, the Launchscreen.xib doesn't appear. and my Images.xcassets is like that : http://i.imgur.com/OSKFsVT.png

Comment: yes, it looks better. Now you need to select the resolutions that you want to support like iPhone 7.0 or prior. Then you need place the same dimension images like I have done here http://imgur.com/8x1sJw2. So you must ask your designer to give you images in all those dimensions :). In inspector view you can look for "size", it will tell you the dimension required. In similar fashion you can take advantage of AppIcon